# Bluetooth headset not connecting windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headphones

I'm using Windows 7 on a Dell laptop, when pairing my bluetooth headset this message appears.

[Image attached, click to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tFug.jpg)

FYI, I have everything installed and set, except when I click Services on the bluetooth device it says (Searching services...) then comes up with the message in the picture attached!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is very old now and likely machines that came with Windows 7 are older now.

Try a USB Bluetooth adapter. There is a good chance a newer adapter will work with your headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 with Microosft Bluetooth driver does not support audio profiles. You have to use third party Bluetooth drivers to be able to connect to handsfree. You can use BlueSoleil drivers for that.